# Compiling assets for wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, sass, gruntjs

I'm working on a WordPress theme (more specifically: a wordpress theme boilerplate) which makes use of SASS (and lots of other technologies). My SASS files are within `assets/sass`. My problem is: how/whereto compile them?

Compiling them into the root directory doesn't feel right, since it gets bloat up - and it is already pretty big (with Grunt, Bower, etc.). *But* the asset path problem (see below) would disappear.

Compiling them into a directory (like `temp` or whatever) wouldn't bloat up my directories but lead to the asset path problem.

The asset path problem:

```
elem { background-image: url('images/foobar.png'); }
```

The path would be correct if the compiled sass file in `assets`, nowhere else. `assets/images/foobar.png` would just work in the root directory.

An important note: it's possible to create a distributable version of the theme with Grunt, where, amongst other things, all styles are concatenated with the `style.css` file in the root directory. The generated `dist` directory then contains only files which should be uploaded to a server or used for distribution (no build files, no sass, no coffee, etc. - just compiled and "finished" files).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I could help you in this, is there a code that I can refer to ? Will be able to give a much more specific answer in that case.

Comment: or maybe you can just provide me with the directory structure, and the Gruntfile

Comment: https://github.com/nehalist/boilerplate pretty messy code (can be considered as "playground"), but there you'll find everything you need (sass, grunt config, etc,). Thanks!

Comment: Great. I really was wishing it would be on GitHub, I will look at it and get back to you :)

Comment: Also did you take a look at this - https://github.com/mattbanks/WordPress-Starter-Theme. See if it solves your issue ?

Comment: Yes, I've looked through a lot of boilerplates, like roots or also the one from mattbanks

Comment: hey what's the issue with compiling everything into a dist folder ?

Comment: Files are compiled into a dist folder, but not during development. Dist folder is for the "finished theme", with all files for the theme (php, js, css, ...)